# PKG can't silent install on Mac Os 10.5

Tags: installation, packagemaker

I have made an Installer by PackageMaler3.0.6 on Mac OS 10.8. Also I have add a JavaScript function in Distribution,This function use for detect the certain App is running or not. Some code like this:

var allProcess = new Array();

allProcess = system.applications.all();

var allProcessCount = allProcess.length;

...

If I normally install (With Installer UI) this pkg on 10.8,10.7,10.5, it's Ok, all function works fine. If i use command line to silent install On 10.8,10.7 it's OK, no error. But if i silent install on 10.5.8, there will be an error in terminal(JavaScript error), can't install. If i remove the code of "var allProcessCount = allProcess.length;"  It can silent install on 10.5.8, once  if added the code like "allProcess.length" ,there will be an error,it looks like can't use the  array property in silent install on 10.5, but 10.7,10.8 it's OK and install with UI it's also Ok on 10.5. Did anyone knows how can i slove this issue? Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug in macOS 10.5.
Why don't you use `system.applications.fromIdentifier(bundleId)`.

It provides information about running processes with a given application identifier (bundle ID). For example, com.apple.TextEdit.

Parameters

```
 bundleID:    A string with the bundle ID of the desired application.
```

Return Value

```
    An array of dictionaries (associative arrays) describing the
 running applications identified by bundleID.
```

Availability

```
Available in Mac OS X v10.4 and later.
```